# asp.net 4 precompile utility and classic asp files

Tags: asp.net, server-side-includes, precompile

We have a huge site that still has over 800 classic asp pages. While working on the upgrade of the site to 4.0 I cam across an issue where asp.net precompile utility aspnet_compiler throws millions of errors in those classic asp pages, especially with the include directives. (mainly constants and functions are defined in the global files not visible in the included file itself)

Is there a way to tell precompile utility to ignore classic asp and inc files?

Is there any other way other then converting all asp pages to make it precompile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete all of the .asp files and see if anyone notices.

Just kidding.

Instead, how about making a copy of the site with no .asp files, and precompile that. Or temporarily delete the .asp files, precompile, then move them back.

But, BTW, welcome to the joy of using obsolete technologies. It just keeps getting worse from here on; it won't get any better.

Comment: haha that would have been nice to get rid of all asp pages, but no we can't do that ))) and we need to setup continuous integration to run on the whole site

Comment: @McLovin: you'll have a much easier time writing unit tests of .NET code than of ASP code. Just a hint.