# Cannot use 'VBScript' because another language has been specified earlier in this page (or was implied from a CodeFile attribute)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vbscript, asp-classic, web-deployment

I created an **Empty** ASP.NET 4.5 Web Application project (selected MVC/WebAPI).

Now I copied my existing classic asp website files(just the regular .asp files, css and images) to these WebApp.

It works fine. Builds on my local box fine.

Now I am trying to publish it with Visual Studio 2013.

I selected File System as publish location. And Option to PreCompile.
But it gives me this error:

```
Cannot use 'VBScript' because another language has been specified earlier in this page (or was implied from a CodeFile attribute).           my_lib.asp                17           0              MyProject.WebApp
```

**If I uncheck PreCompile, it works.**

We are planning in upgrading the classic asp to asp.net but this is our first step and want the WebApp to precompile.

Any ideas?

Note: There are not .cs files as such right now other than the routeconfig etc. that the empty application template generates.

Comment: Sounds like you're mixing C# and VB in your script markup. You should post the relevant bits from your page *in your question*. To figure out what the relevant bits are, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Interesting...I don't recall (being able to) pre-compile classic asp (vbscript/jscript)...probably why unchecking pre-comile "works" (all interpreted at run time - which is how classic asp works). See if [this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5021572/304683) helps...

Comment: You can't compile VBScript. @EdSF, makes a good suggestion, but you don't even have to physically remove the Classic ASP files, just right click in the VS file navigator and exclude them from the project, they'll stay in the directory

Comment: Not sure exactly what did it but the error is gone. Only thing I recall doing is deleting a .cs file which I had excluded from project and there was an not-in-use .aspx file.